# Cannot make Goose DB Migration working for Go testing

Tags: database, testing, go, database-migration

I am currently learning Golang for web programming and now I continue by learning about database,Rest API and testing in Golang.

and now I got an issue with *[Goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose)* database Migration and *Go Testing* integration.

I want to integrate goose migration to my Go testing code, my scenario is to up all migrations before test and then reset all database once testing is done.

my problem is I can't find any documentation/sample code to do it with [Goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose).

I also have tried to execute the [goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose) command using **exec.Command()** but it always returns *exit status 1*

this is my existing code to trigger the migration up before testing being executed:

```
func pretest() {
      var args = []string{
          os.Getenv("DB_SERVER"),
          "\"user=" + os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME") + " dbname=" + os.Getenv("DB_TEST_NAME") + " sslmode=disable\"",
          "up",
      }   

      exe := exec.Command("goose", args...)
      exe.Dir = os.Getenv("DB_MIGRATION")
      /* result, err := exe.Output()*/
      //fmt.Println(string(result))
      /*fmt.Println(err)*/

      output := exe.Run()
      fmt.Println(output)
  }
```

[image]

```
$ go test -v
exit status 1
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok
```

my question is it possible to trigger migration (up/down/reset) from inside Go Code (in this case is testing code) ?

Why **exec.Command()** keep returning *code status 1* but it work well when I execute another linux command (ls, pwd, mkdir are work well in the same way) ?

Comment: Do not post images of text. They are not searchable, or always even readable.  Please copy-and-paste all text content.

Comment: To address your question: `is it possible to trigger migration (up/down/reset) from inside Go Code?` It's possible to do anything you want. What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: @Flimzy just like I've said before, I need to migrate up all migrations before Testing is running and then migrate reset after Testing is done.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I am trying to test my Rest API code which is requiring my  database tables to be prepared before testing is running. and my problem is I can't setup goose migration to migrate up all tables before unit test

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. But I asked _what have you tried_. This means: Show us your code, or explain your attempt. And when you tried that, what happened differently than you expected?

Comment: I am trying to execute following bash command: `goose postgres "user=postgres dbname=teahrm_test sslmode=disable" up` using exec.Command("goose", args...) but still not working, it keeps return status code 1

Comment: Please read, and answer my ENTIRE QUESTION. What happened when you tried that? What were you expecting instead?  "it doesn't work" is _not_ a problem statement.

Comment: I have answered all of your questions, I said that I have tried to execute the goose shell command and the shell command that I executed from Go code was returned status code 1 (error). what I expecting ? of course I want the goose migrate command to generate the tables for me before my testing code being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to `go` as well, so my analysis may be totally wrong but since `goose` seems to be an open source package itself, I took a look at the [cmd/goose/main.go](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/master/cmd/goose/main.go#L78-L80) file that refers to how the commands are called internally:

```
if err := goose.Run(command, db, *dir, arguments...); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("goose run: %v", err)
}
```

Which calls the `Run`func that is defined in the [goose.go](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/master/goose.go#L17)

```
func Run(command string, db *sql.DB, dir string, args ...string) error {
```

That takes argument `command` string argument with db strings as well.

But if you would like to still work with the `execCommand` then maybe you could take a look at [goose_test.go](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/master/goose_test.go) file which which passes arguments `dir` where the migrations are to be run perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this issue solved by changing this following line on my code:

```
"\"user=" + os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME") + " dbname=" + os.Getenv("DB_TEST_NAME") + " sslmode=disable\"",
```

to:

```
"user=" + os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME") + " dbname=" + os.Getenv("DB_TEST_NAME") + " sslmode=disable",
```